# How to simulate game controller key input?

Tags: python, xinput

I am currently working on a program that acts as a USB game controller but I am having trouble finding a way to simulate keypress and stick movement...

I am hoping to work with python but anything will work.

Comment: Two hints to help us help you: Post the code you currently have, and also be more specific about the problem you're having (For example, if you've made it as far as having an error, post the error)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into pyvjoy, it allows you to simulate controllers when the emulator [x360ce](https://www.x360ce.com/) is installed.

Have a look at this rocket league bot framework where the code allows you to simulate input.

Example:

```
import pyvjoy

class PlayHelper:

    def __init__(self, player_index):
        self.device = pyvjoy.VJoyDevice(player_index + 1)

    def update_controller(self, output):
        self.device.data.wAxisX = output[0]
        self.device.data.wAxisY = output[1]
        self.device.data.wAxisZRot = output[2]
        self.device.data.wAxisZ = output[3]
        self.device.data.lButtons = (1 * output[4]) + (2 * output[5]) + (4 * output[6])

        self.device.data.wAxisXRot = 16383
        self.device.data.wAxisYRot = 16383

        self.device.update() # Send data to vJoy device
```

> Source: https://github.com/drssoccer55/RLBot

Comment: How do I install it?